# WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 fails to create proxy service from governance registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I have WSO2 ESB and WSO2 GREG running with registry being mounted to ESB instance.

While trying to create Loging proxy service I picked up the WSDL from registry. The WSDL has a schema import which it depends on. However ESB fails to resolve the schema location trying to find it on the local FS.

Screen [here](http://oi50.tinypic.com/23kf4gk.jpg)

Logs [here](http://pastebin.com/vvUQJUnK).

Can this be overcame? Or that's another bug for WSO2?

Thanks,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exactly the same "SchemaLocation" attribute value used in your WSDL in the "SchemaLocation" attribute of the "resource" element of the "publishWSDL" option.

For example, if the WSDL has a the schema imported as,

```
<schema namespace="some_namespace" schemaLocation="./TestSchema.xsd">
```

Then the "schemaLocation" attribute of the "resource" tag should also have the same as mentioned below.

```
<resource schemaLocation="./TestSchema.xsd" ...>
```

Comment: That's very useful point as Governance Registry save schema files in registry using their target names. So the paths in the WSDLs become very long. Wish ESB could resolve it itself just in default scenario.