# XSD import from file

Tags: wso2-esb

We are in the process of putting a wso2esb server in between our webservices and our customers. I'am having problems with imports and includes in the wsdl-files.

To make the migration simple, we thought we'd copy all the wsdl and xsd files we've got on to a directory on the esb server (but outside of the wso2esb software). In creating the services in the esb, I now refer to the wsdl-files using 'specify source WSDL'.

This does show a wsdl, but not (exactly) the one we've created. So we're using 'useOriginalwsdl=true', 'modifyUserWSDLPortAddress=true', 'showAbsoluteSchemaURL=true'.

In one of our wsdl we'ver got this piece of code:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http: //www.egem.nl/StUF/wsdl/zkn0201.wsdl">
<xs:import schemaLocation="xsd/stuf0204.xsd" namespace="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0204"/>
<xs:import schemaLocation="xsd/zkn0201.msg.xsd" namespace="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0201"/>
</xs:schema>
```

with the above parameters set, this shows in the wsdl of the service as:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/wsdl/zkn0201.wsdl">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/StUF0204" schemaLocation="HAEM_TEST?xsd=xsd/stuf0204.xsd"/> 
<xs:import namespace="http://www.egem.nl/StUF/sector/zkn/0201" schemaLocation="HAEM_TEST?xsd=xsd/zkn0201.msg.xsd"/>
 </xs:schema>
```

But when I query the wsdl with "http:// ...../sevices/HAEM_TEST?xsd=xsd/zkn0201.msg.xsd", it does not return the content of the xsd. Even though the xsd's are presenton disk relative to the actual wsdl used by the service:

On disk:

```
$ ls -lR /some/path/to/my/resource
 .:
  drwx------. 2 wnproesb01 wnproesb01  4096 Apr 17 23:15 xsd
  -rwx------. 1 wnproesb01 wnproesb01  9498 Apr 16 18:31 zkn0201.wsdl

./xsd:
   -rwx------. 1 wnproesb01 wnproesb01  13885 Apr 16 18:31 stuf0204.xsd
   -rwx------. 1 wnproesb01 wnproesb01  63982 Apr 16 18:31 zkn0201.msg.xsd
```

These xsd-files may have imports or includes themselves, given by a relative path compared to themselves.

The big question: what do I need to do, to make this wsdl a valid, working wsdl as presented by the wso2esb? Including all the included/imported xsd's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Registry to store WSDLs and then refer from there. Which is far more convenient than storing in file system.

http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.nl/2012/07/wso2-esb-proxy-from-registry.html

and also refer this on how to define the schema location for WSDL imports correctly.

[WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 fails to create proxy service from governance registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616009/wso2-esb-4-5-0-fails-to-create-proxy-service-from-governance-registry)